# Export Neo4j db creation statements

Tags: neo4j

Such as the example movies database
Is it possible to extract the single statement that creates the current database with all it's properties, relations and nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and use `apoc.export.cypher.all`. From the docs:

> apoc.export.cypher.all(file,config) - exports whole database incl.
>   indexes as cypher statements to the provided file

Comment: i keep getting this:
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.cypher.all`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Export to files not enabled, please set apoc.export.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

[Edit] even after adding it to the conf file

Comment: @MashedPotato edit your neo4j.conf file, find the line apoc.export.file.enabled and set it to true. That is: `apoc.export.file.enabled=true`

Comment: yup that was working i had copied a white space by mistake thanks a lot

Comment: @MashedPotato you are welcome! if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.